# How to include classes

Tags: c++

I've written a couple of classes with method definitions only, and these methods declarations below. At the bottom I have `main()` function.

I want to ask you two questions - what's the best practice including this, and how should I do this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

template <class heap> class Addition {

protected:
    heap a;
    heap b;
    heap outcome;
public:
    Addition(heap, heap);

}; // End Addition

template <class heap> Addition::addition(heap c_a, heap c_b)
{
    a = c_a;
    b = c_b;
}

template <class heap> class Array_Addition: public Addition {

public:
    solve();

}; // End Array_Addition

template <class heap> Array_Addition::solve()
{
    // something here
}

template <class heap> class Struct_Addition: public Addition {

public:
    solve();

}; // End Struct_Addition

int main()
{
    cout << "aaaaa";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Edited, I put the code I have opened currently in my IDE.

Comment: Your classes contain **declarations**, with the **definitions** below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the normal thing to do is to put the class declaration in a header file (Addition.h) to put the methods in another file called Additon.cpp and the calling code in another file , maybe main.cpp. Then include the header file in the 2 .cpps files

Answer (score 0):

```
#include"classnameinthesamefolder.h or .cpp"
```